# How do you reduce the size of GHC's type error messages?

Tags: haskell

For example,

```
test/Spec.hs:42:18: error:
    • No instance for (genvalidity-0.8.0.0:Data.GenValidity.GenUnchecked
                         (Decl UnkindedType Identifier Location))
        arising from a use of ‘forAllUnchecked’
    • In the second argument of ‘it’, namely
        ‘(forAllUnchecked
            (\ decls
               -> shouldBe
                    (either
                       (const ())
                       (const ())
        ... 50 (literally) more lines ...
```

is way too long that I have to scroll up my terminal/message viewer to see what happened. I only need the line number and column.

Is there a GHC flag to make it output just this?

```
test/Spec.hs:42:18: error:
    • No instance for (genvalidity-0.8.0.0:Data.GenValidity.GenUnchecked
                         (Decl UnkindedType Identifier Location))
        arising from a use of ‘forAllUnchecked’
```

This gives me everything I need.

Comment: Maybe this can help you `:set -ferror-spans -freverse-errors -fprint-expanded-synonyms` Found in: http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#ghci.conf

Answer (score 5):

The best I have come up with so far is:

```
-dppr-user-length=0 -dppr-cols=10000
```

which produces

```
test/Spec.hs:42:18: error:
    • No instance for (genvalidity-0.8.0.0:Data.GenValidity.GenUnchecked (Decl UnkindedType Identifier Location)) arising from a use of ‘forAllUnchecked’
    • In the second argument of ‘it’, namely ‘(forAllUnchecked (\ decls -> ...))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: it "Compiler terminates" (forAllUnchecked (\ decls -> ...))
      In the second argument of ‘describe’, namely ‘(do ...)’
   |
42 |                 (forAllUnchecked
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

It's still taking up space, but far fewer lines than before. I will accept better answers.